# Exclude python file from executions with server start in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have some separate python file which fetches data from GitHub and store as dictionary. Execution of these files consumes times which makes django server to run or restart slower. This delay makes development time consuming. What is the proper way to organize external python files in project.
Execution of these file is not required to be executed each time. Fetched can be stored in database and executions can be weekly.

```
myProject>
   home>
    -views.py
    -urls.py
    -ABC.py (file need to exlude)
```

Comment: move the file in a folder that does not have __init__.py.

Comment: OK I tried but Did not work.